# How to make Immunity Debugger Color Scheme look like OllyDbg Color Schemes?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ollydbg

I want to make Immunity Debugger look like default OllyDbg in Color and Style.

Here is how default Olly looks:
[image]

Here is how default Immunity Debugger looks: 
[image]

Changing anything in the color schemes seems to has no effect.

**How to make Immunity Debugger Color Scheme look like OllyDbg Color Schemes?**

Answer (score 1):

Open your Immnunity init file on "..\Immunity Inc\Immunity Debugger\ImmunityDebugger.ini".

Locate the "[Colours]" section.

Change one of the schemes for the following value (I did it on scheme 7):

```
Scheme[7]=0,12,8,18,7,8,7,13
Scheme name[7]=Scheme 7
```

Open Immunity and "right-click" on any screen.
Go to Appearence > Colors (all) > your modified scheme (in my case Scheme 7)

[Screenshot of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9RWL.png)